# Why are static fields null by default?

Tags: c#, class, static

Just curious, from the code below I can see that static field of type A will be null by default while variable of that type needs to be initialized to ahve at least null value. Could anyone explain the difference a bit more? Thanks

```
class Program
{
  static A _a;   //it is null by default
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          A nonStaticA; //empty reference, exception when used
          A correctA=null;
        }
}
class A
{
}
```

Comment: It's not just static fields, it's all fields (class-level variables) that are initialized to their default value (null for reference, 0 for numbers, false for bool, etc).

Comment: what other value should it be ?

Comment: I believe Loj meant that there is no compilation warning/error for the static member as there is for the function variable. This is because the compiler can't assume that the static member is not initialized somewhere (actually it can, but it doesn't). For a local variable the compiler will complain that it is not initialized.

Comment: @Eli Iser Yes that was what I was not sure about. But as fields are always initialized to default values, I think there is no way how one can have static variable which is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between **local variables** and **fields**, not between static and instance.

Local variables of any type are required to be initialized to a value before they are used the first time. This prevents bugs where you forget to initialize a variable.

The compiler can verify this, because local variables only exist inside a single method, and code in a method is executed in a predictable order, from the top town. So it is easy to check if a variable is accessed before it is initialized.

Fields are different. They can be accessed in multiple methods, and there is no way the compiler can determine in which order they are executed. Therefore it cannot check at compile-time that fields are initialized before they are accessed. Instead fields are given a default value, which is `null` for all reference types, `0` for integers and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The initial value of a field, *whether it be a static field or an instance field*, is the default value of the field's type. It is not possible to observe the value of a field before this default initialization has occurred, and a field is thus never "uninitialized".

If a static constructor exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

A local variable is not automatically initialized and thus has no default value. For the purpose of definite assignment checking, a local variable is considered initially unassigned.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `static`. Class fields (instance and static) are initialized to their defaults, local variables are not.

And why? Like lots of things it was a design decision at some point.

Answer (score 0):

C#, as far as I can observes, kept many things as they were in other previous languages, mainly C++.

The reason in C++ (which may or may not be relevant to C#) is that static (or global) objects are statically written into the executable or library while for other objects the code that creates the object (and not the object itself) is written into the executable or library. For objects on the stack usually code that subtracts some value from the stack pointer is written.

When the executable or library is loaded into memory by the OS the static fields are just a bunch of bytes that are copied as is into memory (the data segment of the process). Since they are copied as is, they already have a value (the value in the executable or library file). Because of that there is no performance implications to setting it to a specific value. For that reason (as far as I can see) the C++ standard made their value deterministic (if they are not initialized explicitly) and what is more natural than zero as an initialization value?!

In order to initialize a dynamic object (whether it is on the stack or the heap) code has to be inserted into the executable or library. This has performance implications (and maybe other implications) so the C++ standard preferred to leave it up to the programmer.

I'm not completely sure every bit of this data is true, but it is what seems logical to me from what I know.